# Application Can Not Be Deployed on Cloudhub

Tags: deployment, mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

currently I am working with mule esb in cloud, to achieve this I am using free trial version of Cloudhub. FYI, I am new to cloudhub and right now tring to deploy my mule application there. Unfortunately, everytime I tried to deploy my application, it can not be deployed.

I have tried 2 ways to deploy the apps.

The first one is from the Mule Studio, by following this documentation:

[Deploy Apps to Cloudhub From Mule Studio](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Hello+World+on+CloudHub)

When I tried that way, I got following error:

[image: Error From Mule]

I guess it was because of the proxy.

The second way I tried is by deploying it directly from the cloudhub.io, by following this documentation:

[Deploying Apps Directly From Cloudhub.io](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+a+CloudHub+Application)

But, when I check on the deployment section, I found out, that my application is not uploaded. Then I tried to upload it again, update it, and run the application, but it seems that the application still not uploaded and the change I made is not applied.

Here is the error I got:

[image: Error From Cloudhub]

FYI, before I upload the application to cloudhub, I compressed the application folder into zip file.

How can I solved this problem? Do you think I did something wrong when deploying it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you configure your http endpoint like this:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="${http.port}".... />
```

CloudHub will automatically expand *http.port* property to the correct value.

To make it work deploying from CloudHub you shouldn't compress your project yourself and upload but make Studio create a deployable archive: Right click on your project and then click export, select 'Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive' under Mule category. That will have Mule ESB application structure and should work in CloudHub.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still, I can not solved the problem and still got those error

Comment: Can you run the compressed application in Mule ESB standalone? (I assume that in your CloudHub environment it starts successfully).

Comment: yes! I try to import the zip file to mule studio and run it. It runs! But when I try to deploy it, I got the error.

Comment: I've created this chat room so we can talk about this problem: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56547/application-can-not-be-deployed-on-cloudhub

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar problem, when deploying application in cloud hub, using Mule 3.5. My application inserts Contacts info (FirstName, LastName, Title, Email etc) from CSV file in Salesforce "Contacts" object. With proxy details configured, my application was running fine in local machine but when deployed in cloud hub, I was getting "Unknown host Exception. Root exception in proxy (something similar to this) " exception.

What I did:

I have removed proxy details from Salesforce connector and re-compiled and deployed in cloud hub. When I tested, the contacts from csv file are getting inserted in Salesforce "Contacts" objects.

Note: When Proxy details are removed, it works in cloud hub but fails in local. It seems cloud hub takes care of proxy connection and we don't need to explicitly mention it.

Regards
Ravi Nori

Answer (score 0):

Check your http global endpoint is like that

or you can give in properties file like http.host=0.0.0.0 http.port=8081

these values you can give directly in cloudhub properties.
From flow you can access like ${http.host} , ${http.port} 
First check that domain name is available